# Insert/update table with values from another table for two fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with several fields. Two of them have date keys. I need to insert two new fields to the table updated with the calendar dates. Calendar dates for the two columns are found in a table with the master date key and the corresponding calendar date in a separate field.

So for example;
A single row has 14367 as the date key in DATE KEY EFFECTIVE, and 18434 as the date key in DATE KEY EXPIRATION. I would like those fields to populate based on the corresponding calendar dates to 14367 and 18434 in the Master Date Key table, in two independent columns table 1.

TABLE 1

```
id | Effective Date| Expiration Date| Eff Calendar Date| Exp Calendar Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1095829       | 1840294        | ?                |?
 2 | 1093895       | 1838949        | ?                |?
 3 | 1095289       | 1835019        | ?                |?
 4 | 1093910       | 1840193        | ?                |?
```

TABLE 2

```
Date Master Key| Calendar Date
    -----------------------------
 1095829       | Jan 1
 1093895       | Jan 15
 1095289       | Feb 1
 1093910       | Feb 15
 1840294       | Mar 1
 1838949       | Mar 15
 1835019       | Apr 1
 1840193       | Apr 15
```

Is this possible to do without linking together multiple queries?

Comment: You should really add a sample of your data for our understanding

Comment: Edit: Added data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting

I have never updated a table with the contain of 2 other tables in Access

Updating 1 table with the contain of 1 other table is common. So you can surely achieve what you want with 2 different queries :

**Effective dates:**

```
UPDATE Table1 T
INNER JOIN Table2 Eff ON T.[Effective Date]=Eff.[Date Master Key]
SET T1.[Eff Calendar Date]=Eff.[Calendar Date]
WHERE T.id = 1
```

**Expiration dates:**

```
UPDATE Table1 T
INNER JOIN Table2 Expi ON T.[Expiration Date]=Expi.[Date Master Key]
SET T1.[Exp Calendar Date]=Expi.[Calendar Date]
WHERE T.id = 1
```

---

But I am wondering if Access will accept both updates in a single query, so you can test this first and tell if it worked :

```
UPDATE ((Table1 T
INNER JOIN Table2 Eff ON T.[Effective Date]=Eff.[Date Master Key])
INNER JOIN Table2 Expi ON T.[Expiration Date]=Expi.[Date Master Key])
SET T1.[Eff Calendar Date]=Eff.[Calendar Date], T1.[Exp Calendar Date]=Expi.[Calendar Date]
WHERE T.id = 1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to accomplish the same thing using a 'WHERE' clause twice?

Comment: sure, I added the `WHERE` clauses so it updates only the table1 record having ID 1